# Covariance structure of subject by period random effect in mixed effects model

Tags: glmm

I'm working on a project which is using mixed effects model. There are different group of subjects given different treatment during 2 different periods. There are errors associated with subjects by time effects during the same period and also errors associated with subjects between 2 different periods. The error of subjects within the same period should be a covariance structure of compound symmetry. I'm wondering what's the covariance structure of the subject by period random effects between the 2 periods? How can I simulate the data to show it?